# As i have Switched to react-navigation-drawer but facing a error dunno why

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

the piece of code i tried

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from'react-native';

import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

import HomeScreen from './rootscreen';
import LoginScreen from './loginscreen';
export default function MainScreen() {
 return (
<>
  <MyApp/>
</>
);
}

const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({

Home: {
  screen: HomeScreen
},
Settings: {
  screen: LoginScreen
}
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
 },
});
```

the error i am facing

Failed building JavaScript bundle.
While trying to resolve module `react-navigation-drawer` from file `/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/screen/mainscreen.js`, the package `/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/lib/module/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

Comment: sometimes i face 
'Unable to resolve "react-native-screens" from "node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/lib/module/views/DrawerView.js"'

Answer (score 0):

`"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.7"`
Try installing that package. This should fix your error.